# Why Tommen was called "First of his name" even if there has been a Tomen II Lannister?

Tags: game-of-thrones, a-song-of-ice-and-fire

Why Tommen is called "first of his name" while there has been a [Tommen II Lannister](http://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Tommen_II_Lannister)?

Comment: tsk, tsk.  Asking why the first person named Tommen to be king of all Westeros is not called Tommen the Third seems kind of silly.  Almost as silly as the first ever King of Sicily being Roger II, or the first women named Elizabeth to be Queen of the UK, Antigua and Barbuda, The Bahamas, Barbados, Belize, Canada,  Grenada, Jamaica, Saint Kitts and Nevis, Saint Lucia, Saint Vincent and the Grenadines, Australia, New Zealand, Papua New Guinea, Solomon Islands, and Tuvalu would be called Elizabeth II.  Oops, bad real life examples.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

- Because he is a Baratheon, not a Lannister. After all, his father is [Robert Baratheon](http://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Robert_I_Baratheon), isn't it?
- Because the current numbering dates to Aegon's Conquest:

  > Will Tommen rule as Tommen I of House Baratheon, or Tommen III (?) of House Lannister?
  >
  > Tommen the 1st.
  >
  > The current numbering dates to Aegon's Conquest; the kings of the predecessor 
  >   kingdoms don't count. It was the same in England after the Norman Conquest. Edward Longshanks was Edward I, and never mind all the Saxon Edwards who had come before 1066.
  >
  > <sub>[So Spake Martin, june 2002](http://www.westeros.org/Citadel/SSM/Month/2002/06/)</sub>
- Because he is king of the seven kingdoms, not king of the Rock. Numbers are related to not only the House, but also the Title. There are several historical of monarchs who have different numbers for their different titles, such as:

  - [James VI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/James_VI_and_I), James VI as king of Scotland and James I as king of England and Ireland.
  - [Charles V](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Charles_V,_Holy_Roman_Emperor#Titles), Charles V as Holy Roman Emperor, Charles I as king of Castille and Aragon, Charles IV as king of Naples...
  - [Henri IV](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Henry_IV_of_France) as Henri III of Navarre and Henri IV of France

Comment: Beat me by abt 10 seconds. +1.

Answer (score 5):

Because he was **king** Tommen. The number associated with the king or queen relates to the previous rulers with that same name. That's why there are a [dozen](http://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Aegon_Targaryen) Aegon Targaryen's but only the 5 who are crowned are numbered.

Secondly he is still legally a Baratheon not a Lannister. While many people believe otherwise (and are correct) he still has the Baratheon name by right making him *King Tommen Baratheon, first of his name*.

Answer (score 3):

Tommen II Lannister was King of Westerlands. Tommen is King of Seven Kingdoms. Different title, different number